# No module named 'numpy' while installing scikit-image

Tags: docker, scikit-learn, scikit-image, alpine-linux

I am trying to install scikit-image in alpine docker but for some reason it is keep throwing `No module named 'numpy'` error

Here is the `Dockerfile`

```
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
# Installing System Libraries and Python Dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev make && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
&& pip install -r requirements.txt && apk del gcc musl-dev make
```

And Here is the `requirements.txt`

```
numpy
matplotlib
scikit-image
scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an alpine image and making use of the pip package manager, you need to include in the apk update section as well.

```
FROM alpine
COPY ./requirements.txt /temp/requirements.txt
# Installing System Libraries and Python Dependencies
WORKDIR '/temp'
RUN apk update && apk add --update py-pip && apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev make && ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
&& pip install -r requirements.txt && apk del gcc musl-dev make
```

Since you are using the alpine as the base image, Make sure to add the other packages as well that requires for your requirement libraries.

Comment: I have the same issue and I am using python:3.8.0 image and numpy comes before skimage in the requirements.txt file, any ideas what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I tried to install numpy alone

```
pip install numpy
```

then install the requirements file as follows:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This workaround solved my issue. hope it helped!